# Cannot convert custom iterator to const_iterator

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, containers, const-iterator

I am coding an implementation/copy of the std::vector container, and I am having some issues with its iterators.

My random_access_iterator and vector class are implemented like this:

```
namespace ft
{
    template <typename T>
    class random_access_iterator
    {
        public:
            typedef T value_type;
            typedef value_type* pointer;
            // [...]

        private:
            pointer _ptr;

        public:
            random_access_iterator( void ) : _ptr(pointer()) {}
            random_access_iterator( const random_access_iterator& src ) { *this = src; }
            random_access_iterator& operator= ( const random_access_iterator& src ) { this->_ptr = src._ptr; return *this; }
            // [...]
    };

    template<class T>
    class vector
    {
        public:
            typedef T value_type;
            typedef random_access_iterator<value_type> iterator;
            typedef random_access_iterator<const value_type> const_iterator;
            // [...]

        public:
            vector( void ) {}
            // [...]
    };
}

int main()
{
    ft::vector<int>::iterator it;
    ft::vector<int>::const_iterator cit(it);
    return 0;
}
```

The Copy Constructor of `random_access_iterator<const int>` receiving a `random_access_iterator<int>` in the main function results in a compile-time error:

```
iterator_test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
iterator_test.cpp:39:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘ft::random_access_iterator<const int>::random_access_iterator(ft::vector<int>::iterator&)’
   39 |         ft::vector<int>::const_iterator cit(it);
      |                                               ^
iterator_test.cpp:16:25: note: candidate: ‘ft::random_access_iterator<T>::random_access_iterator(const ft::random_access_iterator<T>&) [with T = const int]’
   16 |                         random_access_iterator( const random_access_iterator& src ) { *this = src; }
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
iterator_test.cpp:16:79: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘ft::vector<int>::iterator’ {aka ‘ft::random_access_iterator<int>’} to ‘const ft::random_access_iterator<const int>&’
   16 |                         random_access_iterator( const random_access_iterator& src ) { *this = src; }
      |                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
iterator_test.cpp:15:25: note: candidate: ‘ft::random_access_iterator<T>::random_access_iterator() [with T = const int]’
   15 |                         random_access_iterator( void ) : _ptr(pointer()) {}
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
iterator_test.cpp:15:25: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

I am using `c++ file.cpp -std=c++98` to compile.

For your information, I am not allowed to use anything newer than C++98.
I would be very thankful if any of you could explain to me why this is wrong and what I could do to make it behave like the SDL.

Comment: Have looked at `std::vector<T>::iterator` implementation as your start point?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  Right now we have to piece together and add our own code to get things to compile and reproduce your error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you for your tip! I've added the minimal reproducible example with everything needed to get the same error as me

Comment: @273K I couldn't find the source code for the implementation, but I am following what is described in cppreference.com

Comment: @dfarhi *I couldn't find the source code for the implementation* -- You are not using an IDE or development environment that takes you to where the declaration/definition of various functions, types, and macros are?  If not, get a better IDE.   For example, in Visual Studio, all you have to do is put the mouse on the item, bring up the context menu, and choose to see the declaration.  It doesn't matter what version of C++ you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by replacing the CopyConstructor and CopyAssignementOverload with

```
template<typename U>
random_access_iterator( const random_access_iterator<U>& src ) { *this = src; }
template<typename U>
random_access_iterator& operator= ( const random_access_iterator<U>& src ) { this->_ptr = src._ptr; return *this; }
```

and by adding a `template<typename U> friend class random_access_iterator;` private member

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `random_access_iterator<T>` and `random_access_iterator<const T>` are two different and independent classes, jence the compiler does not know how to construct one from another - you need to teach it by providing a constructor (for this case, it is better to have an implicit constructor).

```cpp
template <typename T>
class random_access_iterator
  /* ... */

 private:
  // Make two iterator classes `friend`s to access private `ptr_`
  template <typename U>
  friend class random_access_iterator;

  /* ... */

 public:
  /* ... */

  // This constructor is only enabled for `const_iterator` to allow "const promotion" of iterators.
  template <bool is_const = std::is_const_v<value_type>,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<is_const>>
  random_access_iterator(
      random_access_iterator<std::remove_const_t<value_type>> iter) : ptr_(iter.ptr) {}

};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But sadly, for this project, all code must be compliant with the C++98 Standard and I believe the `remove_const_t` template is C++11 and newer only

Comment: it should be trivial to implement both `std::remove_const_t` and `std::enable_if_t` in c++98 too. See possible implementation on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv.